# Referenced file contains errors (project-aware:/spring-tool-4.2.xsd). maven

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, xsd

Why am i getting this error in my xml configuration

> Referenced file contains errors (project-aware://Registeration/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-4.2.xsd). For more information, right click on the message in the 
>        Problems View and select "Show Details..."

This is the header xml file....

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: It is complaining of this xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

Comment: I am getting this on a project, but with amqp xsd.  Ever get to the source of this problem?